# Tall valve on toilet

Tags: plumbing

My toilet has been prematurely refilling every so often so I want to change out the flange and I realized that it’s this taller one. I’ve never seen one like this, so I don’t know how to replace it or if I can without taking the whole toilet apart.
[image]

Comment: Not answering the question of how to replace this unusual flapper, but it doesn't look so old or damaged.   It may just have calcium build-up, which is easy to scrape off with a fingernail.   There must be some easy way to remove it, which will make it easier to clean.

Comment: CLR removes limescale, as does vinegar.

Comment: What's your question? Eljer is a common enough brand that replacement parts should be readily available. Please revise your post title to ask something specific.

Answer (score 1):

The "premature refill"  Is most all the time associated with the rubber flush valve seal seeping some water into the bowl.
Sometimes it's just a cleaning of the seat and the seal. (the green seal in your pic and the seat it is on.)
Other times the seal needs replacing.

It looks as if you removed part of the fill valve. Unless the toilet is filling and running into the overflow tube, and cannot be adjusted for a correct fill height, that is not your problem.

BTW: the fill valve is removed by shutting off and disconnecting the water line and taking the anchoring nut off from the underside.